# Navigate local folder on server using browser. Somewhat like using file://

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to create a webservice where you can browse a specific folder (and subfolders) on a drive on the server that runs the service. It needs to be much like browsing a local file using file://

My question is: Can I somehow relay file:// from the browser to the client. (However I cannot use file:// from the client to connect to the servers ip because of some security restrictions)

Otherwise do you know of a library that does this?
It seems quite extensive for my project to write an in-browser file explorer

Comment: i think this is related to enable directory browsing in iis?

Comment: It kind of is, but I think directory browsing allows all files on the server to be browsed. It is important that it is only a certain folder that is available

Comment: i think we can restrict the folder if we do not want to browse in iis also. please have a look at this if it can help?https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/29587/allow-directory-listing-for-subdirectories-only